# How do I write a date in app.config file?

Tags: c#, .net, date, web-config, app-config

I need to be able to define a date in app.config file. How do I do this and then retrieve it using c#?

Answer (score 14):

Store the value in the config file:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="DateKey" value="2012-06-21" />
</appSettings>
```

Then to retrieve the value you van use:

```
var value = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DateKey"];

var appDate = DateTime.Parse(value);
```

Comment: Whats about Culture: en-US, es-ES, etc ?

Comment: this is old, but today still valid if you change to: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"]

Answer (score 6):

It's easy to use the Settings in Visual Studio. Simply add settings by opening the properties for your project then go to `Settings` and click "The project does not contain a default settings file. Click here to create one.".

Go to the Settings and add a DateTime and define your `date`. 
[image]

To access the Setting in code you simply do this.

`DateTime myDate = Properties.Settings.Default.MyDate;`

Answer (score 3):

Not sure If I fully understand your question. I think that you want to:

You can define date in your **app.config** in the appSettings section:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="DateX" value="21/06/2012"/>
</appSettings>
```

And retrieve AppSettings entry by doing something similar to this:

```
Datetime dateX;
System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig1 = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);
if (rootWebConfig1.AppSettings.Settings.Count > 0)
{
        System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationElement customSetting =       rootWebConfig1.AppSettings.Settings["DateX"];
        if (customSetting != null)
        {
          dateX = Datetime.Parse(customSetting.Value);
        }
}
```

You can check this MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610xe886.aspx) for more help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're referring to the `<appSettings>` element then you're short-of-luck initially: each key is associated with a string value.

Therefore you can see you just need to serialize the DateTime value to a string, and then parse it back when you read it back.

If you don't care about your app.config being edited by humans in notepad, then I'd store the 64-bit ticks value as a string integer:

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["date"] = myDateTime.Ticks.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Read it back by doing this:

```
Int64 ticks = Int64.Parse( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["date"], NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
DateTime myDateTime = new DateTime( ticks );
```

However if you do want to make it human-readable then use the roundtrip option:

```
// Serialise
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["date"] = myDateTime.ToString("o"); // "o" is "roundtrip"
// Deserialise
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Parse( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["date"], NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ) );
```

A few notes:

- My code is advisory and rough. In reality you'd ensure all DateTime instances are in UTC first and then apply an timezone offsets if necessary.
- You'd check if AppSettings contains a key named "date" first, and if not return a default or zero-equivalent answer.
- You'd also avoid .Parse methods and use TryParse instead and handle error conditions as appropriate for your application.

Answer (score 0):

however you want! I mean, a string, but beyond that your options are limitless. If you wanted to, you could store it as a children's book about a date. Just a matter of parsing it wherever you need to use it. But I'd suggest looking into DateTime.ToLongDateString in C# code somewhere, learning that pattern, and storing it like that.